# Derive based on Date and Time

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a column CREATE_DATE of type TimeStamp having the values:

```
24-MAR-17 06.37.58.415000000 PM
01-APR-17 04.37.06.000000000 AM
```

I need to derive a column value based on the timing

if 12:00am between 2:00pm the column should be the same date, else the column should be one day plus the date.

How to achieve that?

Comment: What is the data type of this column?  You've tagged it `date` and the column name implies that it's a `date` but the string representation implies that it's a `timestamp` since dates don't have fractional seconds.  Or maybe it's a `varchar2`.

Comment: Updated the question. The column is a timestamp

Comment: OK.  And what do you want returned exactly?  Should the first row be transformed into 25-MAR-17 06.37.58.415000000 PM (exactly 1 day later)?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, first row as 25-MAR-17 and second row as 01-APR-17

Comment: Yes, it should be exactly 1 day later  25-MAR-17 06.37.58.415000000 PM?  Or do you want to return 25-MAR-17 00.00.00.000000000 AM (midnight the next day)?  Or something else?  "25-MAR-17" is ambiguous.  Unless you want to return that exact string.

Comment: Exactly the date, 25-MAR-17

Comment: An Oracle date always has a time component.  Do you want to return a `date` of 25-MAR-17 00:00:00 rather than a timestamp?  And then for the second row a `date` that omits the fractional seconds from the input `timestamp` (since all the rows need to be of the same data type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you just want the date component.

I would suggest just adding 10 hours and converting to a date:

```
select trunc(create_date + interval '10' hour) as the_date
```

How does this work?  Well 10 hours after 1:30 pm. is 11:30 p.m., so that is on the same date.  10 hours after 2:01 p.m. is 12:01 a.m., which is on the next date.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12c, you can generate the value with a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  created_date TIMESTAMP,
  offset_date  TIMESTAMP
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                 CASE
                 WHEN created_date - TRUNC(created_date) <= INTERVAL '14' HOUR
                 THEN created_date
                 ELSE created_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
                 END
               )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( created_date )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-03-24 18:37:58.415000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-04-01 04:37:06.000000000' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CREATED_DATE | OFFSET_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2017-03-24 18:37:58.415000 | 2017-03-25 18:37:58.415000 |
> | 2017-04-01 04:37:06.000000 | 2017-04-01 04:37:06.000000 |

If you did not want to "derive" the column in the table then you can use the same technique in a `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT created_date,
       CASE
       WHEN created_date - TRUNC(created_date) <= INTERVAL '14' HOUR
       THEN created_date
       ELSE created_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       END As offset_date
FROM   table_name;
```

If you want the time component to be `00:00:00` (Midnight) then just wrap the `created_date` being output in a call to `TRUNC`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  created_date TIMESTAMP,
  offset_date  DATE
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                 CASE
                 WHEN created_date - TRUNC(created_date) <= INTERVAL '14' HOUR
                 THEN TRUNC(created_date)
                 ELSE TRUNC(created_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
                 END
               )
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0dd9783cbcead39285d9c06503ef1d77)*

Answer (score 0):

You can compare (date_col - trunc(date_col)) with NUMTODSINTERVAL(2,'HOUR') and based on comparison you can increment date.